# Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema when join two Pcollections

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I hope all is good for you.

I have two PCollection and I want to apply a leftOuterJoin but when I do this apply, I have this error and I don't understand why : **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema**

```
final PCollection<ClassA> classA = BigQueryReader.getClassA(pipeline, configuration.getBigQueryOptions());
final PCollection<ClassB> classB = BigQueryReader.getClassB(pipeline, configuration.getBigQueryOptions());

final PCollection<Row> join = classA
                .apply("Apply Join",
                        Join.<ClassA, ClassB>leftOuterJoin(classB).using("id1", "id2"));
```

Someone can help to understand why this error happens.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a [schema transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#662-schema-transforms). Such a built-in transform can only be used if all PCollections involved have an associated schema.

Since I have only worked with the Python SDK I cannot tell you how to define a Beam schema in Java, but you can check the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas) for the syntax/definition.